# Is it bad practice to add event listeners inline while creating elements in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, class, methods

I'm dynamically creating and rendering div tag using a JS class, like this:

```js
class CreateNote {
  constructor(title, body) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.render = () => {

      // Create div 1 & 2 and give them the same class name

      const div1 = document.createElement('div');
      div1.className = 'notes-inner-container';

      const div2 = document.createElement('div');
      div2.className = 'notes-prev';

      const hr = document.createElement('hr');
      hr.className = 'notes__line';

      // Nest 'div2' inside 'div1'

      div1.appendChild(div2);
      div1.appendChild(hr);

      /*
        Create Paragraph 1 & 2 and give them the same
        class name and some text
      */

      const p1 = document.createElement('p');
      p1.innerText = this.title;

      const p2 = document.createElement('p');
      p2.className = 'notes-prev__body';
      p2.innerText = this.body;

      // Nest p 1 & 2 inside 'div2'

      div2.appendChild(p1);
      div2.appendChild(p2);

      // Get the body tag and append everything

      const notesDiv = document.querySelector('.notes');
      notesDiv.appendChild(div1);
    }
  }
}
```

I need to add an event listener to this div. But as it takes some time for this div to actually get rendered, when I try to attach the listener to it, it keeps returning a `null` value. The solution I found for this issue is if I add the event listener **inside** my render method, like this:

```js
// Previous chunk of code
const div1 = document.createElement('div');

div1.className = 'notes-inner-container';

div1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Do something;
}

// Next chunk of code
```

And then I was wondering, is this a bad practice? If so, which way would you do it? If you need more information please let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: why isn't the class name notes-inner-container part of the JSX itself? Typically you add EventListeners to componentdidmount so that they set once the JSX of the component has ben rendered

Comment: @UdenduAbasili What JSX are you talking about?

Comment: I'd recommend to make `render` a normal method not an arrow function created in the constructor, but apart from that everything is fine with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is pretty standard. I would define your event listener separately though and just pass it in:

```
// at class level

const handleClick = event => { /* handle onClick event */ }

// inside render method

const div = document.createElement('div')

div.className = 'notes-inner-container'
div.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```